# Restriction of string sizes in certain scenarios

Tags: javascript, xml, nodes

I have a page's div tag data of varying size each time the webpage reloads being placed in an XML by a php file which is then grabbed by a js file, and then with the help of $_POST, being then sent over to another php for email purposes.

My project really just requires a link to the XML file which I have and there's no problem with that. But I was curious about being able to take the childnode that contains literally tens of thousands of characters and being able to place it in the email at the end with the link to the XML file.
What I'm seeing though is that even though my XML page has node in the following format,

```
<info>
   <id>id number</id>
   <content>10's of thousands of characters<content>
</info>
```

If I write this code below send each variable to the console, it only displays about 4,060 characters each time.

```
var k = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contents")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

If I make further variables as below, it displays further into the node.

```
var l = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contents")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
var m = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contents")[0].childNodes[2].nodeValue;
```

But I don't understand why this is happening in the first place. There's a single string in one child node. Why can't the console recognize that unless there's a string size limit (which I don't THINK there is in a normal situation)?

Comment: Why do you think variables can hold unlimited data?

Comment: Ok well I guess in my mind I know that there is a limit basically to everything, but it just seems odd that I would be able to reach the limit that easily. I would imagine there are ways to move around strings of immense sizes.
Like I said, it's not critical for my work right now, I'm just merely curious about it.

Comment: Of course there are ways, but sticking everything in one large variable is rarely _"the way"_ in any language.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link to the duplicate question. I did search this on here but didn't come across that specific answer and it was detailed quite nicely.